# How do I get the last numbers of a number variable?

Tags: python, numbers

I know how to get the *last* digit of a number variable:

```
num = 21
if num % 10 == 1:
    num = num % 10
    print '%s' % num
```

Which will return 1.
But how do I get the last *few* digits of a variable?
Eg. I had

```
bytes = input("Bytes: ")
```

for the sample, I wanted to strip off the last 8 digits to convert it into an amount in GB. Now I need to strip of the last 8 digits and save it to another variable for another use. Then using the 8 remaining digits and strip off 5 to get MB. How do I strip off some digits off the end and save it to another variable?

Comment: your question should be `How do I get the last digit of a number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not convert to a string, slice, and then convert back?

```
num = 12345678
first_four = int(str(num)[:4])
last_four = int(str(num)[4:])
middle_two = int(str(num)[3:5])
```

It's not exactly elegant, but it is simple.

Answer (score 0):

You want to drop the final k digits of value n? That's `n // 10**k` in Python 2.

You want to separate n into the leading digits and then the final k digits? `n_msd, n_lsd = divmod(n, 10**k)`

I wrote "msd" for "most significant digits" and "lsd" for "least ..."

Comment: Thanks, but how do I save the dropped digits to another variable?

Answer (score 0):

If you can install the library. [hurry.filesize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hurry.filesize) can help you to convert number to file size format.

If not, you can use a loop to store number in variable and calculate it.

```
def size_cul(num):
    for x in ['bytes', 'Kb', 'Mb', 'Gb']:
        if -1024 < num < 1024:
            return "%3.1f %s" % (num, x)

        num = num / 1024.0
    return "%3.1f %s" % (num, 'TB')

print(size_cul(1024))
```

Output:

```
1.0 Kb
```

Comment: Also, [humanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/humanize). It is more generalized to humanization since it can also convert numbers, dates etc., but it's name is better.